# How do I print a diagonal line of x? in python

Tags: python

I have an assignment where i have to make a diagona line of x as tall as the input is. If input is 3:

```
x
 x
  x
```

But I have only managed to get the right amount of x on the diagonal but it also prints the diagonal the same number of times.

I have this so far:

```
print("Input the height")
height = int(input())
line = 0
column = 0
while column != height:
    
    column = column + 1

    print()
    line = line + 1
    for i in range(height):
        print(' '*i, end = 'x\n')
```

Comment: You only need one loop, not nested loops.

Comment: Just use the `for` loop for the lines. `' '*i` is doing the columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Such a simple mistake but I just could not get it right :)

Comment: It's a minor thing, but if you provide your prompt to `input` you don't need to separately print it.  `height = int(input("Input the height"))`

Comment: You can even do this as a one-liner somewhat gracefully by spreading the different rows as args to `print`:  ```print(*(' ' * i + 'x' for i in range(int(input("Input the height")))), sep='\n')```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop here. In the code you provided, you have nested loops where the inner loop (`for i in range(height)`) is printing the 'x' character along with the spaces for every iteration of the outer loop. This results in the diagonal being printed multiple times.

```py
height = int(input("Height:"))

for i in range(height):
    print(' ' * i + 'x')
```

The above code does the following:

- Iterates over the range of `height`.
- For each iteration, it prints `i` spaces (`' ' * i`), where `i` is the current iteration index, followed by the character 'x'.
- As `i` increases with each iteration, the 'x' moves one space to the right, forming a diagonal line.

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't need to strip whitespace off the string before converting to int.

Answer (score 0):

You have one loop too many. You can accomplish this using just your inner loop.

```
>>> height = 3
>>> for i in range(height): print(' ' * i + 'x')
... 
x
 x
  x
```

Note, we can create the padding with `str.rjust`, which right justifies the string to a certain width.

```
>>> for i in range(height):
...   print('x'.rjust(i + 1))
... 
x
 x
  x
```